# Difference between presentation model and MVVM

Tags: user-interface, mvvm, presentation-model

I was reading about these two architectures. But I am not able to differentiate between two. In PM the presenter enriches model data and view contains controller(MVC controller) logic which is same case of MVVM.

I have read many articles, each gives definition but difference between them is not described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM is a derivation of PM, both of which are designed for Rich UI, which is different from MVC.

Because of the benefits of WPF, such as DataBinding and Commanding, Presenter evolves into another model specially designed for the View, so called ViewModel.